# OpenCV haar training with images that have transparency

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, transparency, detection, training-data

I'll be using OpenCV's cascade training functions.
But before that I need to prepare training data.
I just want to know if OpenCV can support it if my positive samples have transparency? Like for example if I want the classifier to learn how a vehicle looks, then can I supply positive sample images that have vehicles standing on a transparent background?

Comment: Note that the cascade training computes feature vectors from **grayscale** images. (The haar features are basically sum of pixel intensities over image regions subtracted by sum over other regions.) so having transparent background is equivalent to giving a background of "solid" color. In fact OpenCV automatically discard the alpha channel if you use imread to read in the image.

Comment: Does that mean that I can't provide my samples in color? I have to convert them all to grayscale beforehand?

Comment: You can provide color samples, opencv will translate it to greyscale automatically

Comment: @lightalchemist if OpenCV will treat a transparent color as a solid color, how "close" is this solid color to the color white? I'm asking because I put the vehicles on a transparent background simply because they were white, and in their natural background, the sky was almost white too, so there was very little contrast between the sky and the vehicle edge. So in order to make samples clearer for training, I separated the vehicle from its background and put it on a transparent background. But if "transparent" will amount to a color like white for OpenCV, then again the contrast will be bad.

Comment: After the alpha channel is thrown away the default value for the "transparent" region is set to 0, i.e., pure black. You can try this on your computer by doing ``Mat I = imread("transparent.png"); imshow(I);``

Comment: Thanks, but this would create serious contrast problems for vehicles' tyres which are black... so what would a reasonable solution be to ensure that positive samples have good contrast with their background, so that classification is more accurate? Or does this contrast issue even matter?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, the haar features are only computed on the grayscale image. This might pose a problem as you mentioned, when the default color of 0 might cause the "wheels" to lose contrast. You can probably "standardize" the transparent color rather than have it default to 0.

The first thing is you can load in all 4 channels (including your alpha channel) and then use the alpha channel to set the transparent part to a certain value.

## Python version

```
I = cv2.imread("image.jpg", cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
alpha = I[:, :, 3]
G = cv2.cvtColor(I, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
G[alpha == 0] = 125  # Set transparent region to 125. Change to suit your needs.
```

## C++

```
vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(I, channels);
cv::Mat alpha = channels[3];
alpha = 255 - alpha;  // Invert mask so we select the transparent regions.
cv::Mat G = cv::cvtColor(I, cv::COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
G.setTo(cv::Scalar(125), alpha);
```

As a note of caution, I think you might have to be careful about some of the operations above, e.g., loading image with alpha and "alpha = 255 - alpha;". I believe they are only available only in later versions of OpenCV. I'm using OpenCV 2.4.7 and it works (for the python version. I haven't tried the C++ but it should be the same). So if things don't work, check whether these operations are supported for your version of OpenCV. If not there are ways to get round them.